# Get date from the last month using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have this function to get the date from any weekday from the last month:

```
def set_specific_date_based_on_given_date(week, day_of_the_week):
   today = date.today()
   monday = None
   if week == "this_week":
      monday = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
   elif week == "last_week":
      monday = today - timedelta(weeks=1, days=today.weekday())
   elif week == "two_weeks_ago":
      monday = today - timedelta(weeks=2, days=today.weekday())
   elif week == "three_weeks_ago":
      monday = today - timedelta(weeks=3, days=today.weekday())
   if day_of_the_week == "monday":
      return monday
   elif day_of_the_week == "tuesday":
      return monday + timedelta(days=1)
   elif day_of_the_week == "wednesday":
      return monday + timedelta(days=2)
   elif day_of_the_week == "thursday":
      return monday + timedelta(days=3)
   elif day_of_the_week == "friday":
      return monday + timedelta(days=4)
   elif day_of_the_week == "saturday":
      return monday + timedelta(days=5)
   elif day_of_the_week == "sunday":
      return monday + timedelta(days=6)
```

it works sending the week and the weekday but is there a more efficient way to do this? I want to find a better way than using so many if

Comment: you have `elif week == 'last_week'` three times... what does this accomplish after the first one?

Comment: sorry my bad, I edited my question @Joshua Voskamp

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of the function? Eg. What is the purpose for passing the strings and getting the previous weeks date back?

Answer (score 2):

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

def set_specific_date_based_on_given_date(week,day_of_week):
    day_map = {
        'monday':       0,
        'tuesday':      1,
        'wednesday':    2,
        'thursday':     3,
        'friday':       4,
        'saturday':     5,
        'sunday':       6,
    }

    week_map = {
        'this_week':        0,
        'last_week':        1,
        'two_weeks_ago':    2,
        'three_weeks_ago':  3,
    }

    if week not in week_map or day_of_week not in day_map:
        raise ValueError("""Supplied `week` or `day_of_week` """\
            """not found in allowed values""")
    
    return (today := date.today())\
        - timedelta(weeks=week_map[week], days=today.weekday())\
        + timedelta(days=day_map[day_of_week])


if __name__=="__main__":
    print(set_specific_date_based_on_given_date('three_weeks_ago','monday'))
```

Comment: You can combine the last two `timedelta`

Comment: You should also check that supplied week and day are present as keys in the dictionaries.

Comment: @not_speshal yes, I agree, though perhaps this makes it clearer how the solution was arrived at (readability and all that)

Comment: thank you @JoshuaVoskamp, exactly what I'm looking for